# How can I multiply the integer arguments in the numpy array?

Tags: python

I am creating a program that has a function that takes in four integer arguments which are put into a Numpy array. The function is supposed to print the type of array: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (which it does) and then print the multiplication of the four items in the array(that's the part I am having trouble with). Any hits on what to do? I am a beginner. Thank you

```
enter code hereimport numpy as np
import sys
def array(x1, x2, x3, x4):

    x1 = int(x1)
    x2 = int(x2)
    x3 = int(x3)
    x4 = int(x4)



class Numpy():
    pass

np.arange(4)
array_1 = np.arange(4)
print(type(array_1))
array_1 = np.multiply(x1,x2,x3,x4)

x1 = sys.argv[1]
x2 = sys.argv[2]
x3 = sys.argv[3]
x4 = sys.argv[4]

array_1 = array(x1, x2, x3, x4)
print(array_1)
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @OnY the output says <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. I also wanted the function to multiply the four arguments x1,x2,x3,x4  and print the product

Comment: Please edit your code, there is no 'print' for the multiplication result

Comment: @OnY I added the print(array_1) but now I get the error x1 is not defined. That is a common error I get that a variable is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's `reduce` function to apply a reducing function to your array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> values = np.arange(1, 5)
>>> values
[1 2 3 4]
>>> np.multiply.reduce(values)
24
>>> np.add.reduce(values)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

#this worked for me now

```
import numpy as np
x1 = input("Enter first number:")
x2 = input("Enter second number:")
x3 = input("Enter third number:")
x4 = input("Enter forth number:")
def array_1(x1,x2,x3,x4):

class Numpy():
    pass

np.arange(4)
array_1 = np.arange(4)
print(type(array_1))

x1 = int(x1)
x2 = int(x2)
x3 = int(x3)
x4 = int(x4)
a = [x1,x2,x3,x4]
result = np.prod(a)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).